# darkmode toggle keeps changing back on relod?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to achieve that the icon changes and stays if darkmode is activated i.e. if dark mode is true icon will be sun dark mode false icon is moon.

However, after reload of the page the page itself is still in dark mode because it's stored in local storage but the icon changes back.

In other words what I'm trying to acheive is

darkmode = enabled then icon sun
darkmode = null the icon moon

```
<button
          id="dark-mode-toggle"
          class="dark-mode-toggle"
          area-label="toggle dark mode"
        >
          <i class="bx bx-moon moon" id="moon"></i>
          <i class="bx bx-sun sun" id="sun"></i>
        </button>
```

```
/* Darkmode */
.dark-mode-toggle {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#moon {
  color: var(--a-clr);
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: block;
}

#sun {
  font-size: 2rem;

  color: var(--a-clr);
  display: block;
}
```

```
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");
const sun = document.getElementById("sun");
const moon = document.getElementById("moon");
const darkModeToggle = document.querySelector("#dark-mode-toggle");

const enableDarkMode = () => {
  document.documentElement.classList.add("darkmode");
  localStorage.setItem("darkMode", "enabled");
};

const disableDarkMode = () => {
  document.documentElement.classList.remove("darkmode");
  localStorage.setItem("darkMode", null);
};

darkModeToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  darkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");

  if (darkMode !== "enabled") {
    enableDarkMode();
  } else {
    disableDarkMode();
  }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: `let darkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");` — So you read the value from localStorage into a variable and then you … **completely ignore it**. Why shouldn't the styling disappear between reloads?

Answer (score 1):

You need to initially update the status of your icon from `darkMode`

Try adding this into your Javascript.

```
if (darkMode === "enabled") {
  enableDarkMode();
} else {
  disableDarkMode();
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to write the same thing. `localStorage` does not clear itself on its own on a page reload.